# Connections pending Apache + Tomcat Setup

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat6

I have a Web App deployed using Tomcat . I'm also using Apache to do the port forwarding from 80 to 8080.
I have an API service passing from apache to tomcat which gets large number of hits per day from a single IP.
And other API service requests from other IP's which are considerably small.
The API service which gets large number of hits sometimes takes 30mins to hit the server (they stay pending somewhere and in queue). Whereas at the same time other IP's do not face any issue. They work perfectly fine.

How is that possible? Does Apache limit something for IP's.
Not being the server guy, but being a startup guy, I have to figure this out myself.
How to resolve the issue where these large number of hits do not get the delay?

Also is it from the Apache side or the Tomcat side , that the delay is being caused?
And also how and where does the queuing work?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it would. Do you have any firewalling in place or use software like fail2ban?

Comment: @Peter no no firewall or any other software is there. Its a ubuntu AWS server.

Comment: Still waiting for somebody to answer this

Comment: You are going to need to post a lot more information about your config. Then either add a bounty or re-ask the question.